# Windows 7 Incorrect Scaling

Tags: windows-7, dpi, scaling

I ran into a problem the second after installing Windows 7 a few months ago, but it only affected a few applications at the time, so I ignored it. Now an increasing number of applications behave the same way and it's annoying. The DPI settings seem to have an issue as can be seen below:

[image: Bad]

The same application *should* look like this:

[image: Good]

The DPI is set to 100% (I tried changing it but it had no effect). I think perhaps the Regional / Language settings have something to do with it but I can't turn it off to English only.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not allowed to have two links in the description. But for example this is how the program normally should look:

http://c.ask.nate.com/imgs/qrsi.tsp/8861288/11823503/0/1/A/01.jpg

(dont mind the windows classic theme, it happens on all themes)

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: 1024x768 (....)

Comment: You could right-click on the Shortcut to the program and choose properties. Under the Compatibility tab, check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings." Click OK and start the program. Does this fix the problem for that program ?

Answer (score 10):

This is a known bug that affects users with a high resolution display.

During installation, Windows 7 installs a larger font set which is 125% of the normal size. If you then choose go back to the standard font size (100%), Windows will keep some of the large fonts even though everything else is adjusted for standard fonts, causing some programs to display incorrectly as the DPI is too big for the window size.

1. Open the **Start menu** and type `regedit` and press **Enter**.
2. Locate the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
3. Find the value `MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24`
4. Change from `SSERIFF.FON` to `SSERIFE.FON`
5. Find `MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24`
6. Change from `SERIFF.FON` to `SERIFE.FON`
7. Find Courier `10,12,15`
8. Change from `COURF.FON` to `COURE.FON`

Restart Windows and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: The pleasure's all mine.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the desktop, click on Personalize > Window Color > Advanced appearance settings and change the font sizes there.  Or you could just set everything to the default theme and see what happens.

Comment: I can't speak for the original asker of this question, but it appears he tried changing the DPI using this approach and set it to 100%, only to have certain programs still scale too large.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 7 32 Bit SP1, I have downloaded the application MemSet4.1, and it comes all fine on my screen.  Changing the DPI settings doesn't have any impact on its display.  Changing screen resolution also doesn't cut off the content, as you have shown in your screen.  Even working with different languages doesn't have any impact on output.  In all such cases, I get the correct result,  so, in fact I don't see the issue on my machine.

I think, you should look for the Display driver installed in your machine, and if correct driver is not installed and default from windows is used, then you need to install the correct display driver.

Answer (score 0):

Response by Ian Atkin helped me a lot, in my case "right" font file names were slightly different, maybe because of other regional settings:

Open the Start menu and type regedit and press Enter.
Locate the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts

Find the value MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24
Change from SSERIFF**R**.FON to SSERIFE**R**.FON

Find MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24
Change from SERIFF**R**.FON to SERIFE**R**.FON

Find Courier 10,12,15
Change from COURF**R**.FON to COURE**R**.FON

Thank you very much Ian Atkin, maybe my little note will help others as well

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @ian-atkin didn't fix it but helped me discover these font locations which led me to my issue/solution:

For some reason, a local application of mine filled in its own version of MS Sans Serif making the fonts look really tiny. Had to change it back its original values.