# Windows 7 Inconsistent DPI/Scaling

Tags: windows-7, dpi, scaling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Incorrect Scaling](https://superuser.com/questions/162692/windows-7-incorrect-scaling)

I've got a Windows 7 box displaying some rather odd behavior related to DPI scaling. This was a laptop provided to me pre-configured to use 125% DPI scaling. Because I always use the machine in a dock with larger monitors, I changed the setting back to 100% (96 DPI).  I did this via the usual mechanism, Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Display, and set the scaling to "Smaller - 100%". I've also confirmed that in the "Custom text DPI" settings, the scale is set to 100% / 96 DPI. The checkbox marked "Use Windows XP style scaling" is *unchecked*.

Here's the issue: Most applications appear to be scaled correctly, but some still appear to be scaled to about 125%. For example, this screenshot of the ATTO Disk Benchmark tool was taken on a clean install of Windows 7 from a different machine:

[image: Properly scaled application]

And looks to be scaled correctly to 96 DPI.

This screenshot, however, was taken on the machine demonstrating the scaling issue:

[image: Application showing incorrect scaling]

Here's another example, the installer for a Stardock application, showing large text/buttons and choppy rescaling of the logo image:

[image: Another improperly scaled application]

I've poked around for any other scaling related settings and found nothing. I'm basically out of ideas. Any advice/assistance in solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: After posting this question I discovered [this](http://superuser.com/questions/162692/windows-7-incorrect-scaling?rq=1) similar one, but it was not ever answered.

Comment: I no not believe the above linked question to be an exact duplicate.